# How to join a list of strings in Ansible?

Tags: ansible

In Ansible, I have a list of strings that I want to join with newline characters to create a string, that when written to a file, becomes a series of lines. However, when I use the join() filter, it works on the inner list, the characters in the strings, and not on the outer list, the strings themselves. Here's my sample code:

```
# Usage: ansible-playbook tst3.yaml --limit <GRP>
---
- hosts: all
  remote_user: root

  tasks:

  - name: Create the list
    set_fact:
        my_item: "{{ item }}"
    with_items:
      - "One fish"
      - "Two fish"
      - "Red fish"
      - "Blue fish"
    register: my_item_result

  - name: Extract items and turn into a list
    set_fact:
        my_list: "{{ my_item_result.results | map(attribute='ansible_facts.my_item') | list }}"

  - name: Examine the list
    debug:
        msg: "{{ my_list }}"

  - name: Concatenate the public keys
    set_fact:
        my_joined_list: "{{ item | join('\n') }}"
    with_items:
      - "{{ my_list }}"

  - name: Examine the joined string
    debug:
        msg: "{{ my_joined_list }}"
```

I want to get output that looks like:

```
One fish
Two fish
Red fish
Blue Fish
```

What I get instead is:

```
TASK: [Examine the joined string] *********************************************
ok: [hana-np-11.cisco.com] => {
    "msg": "B\nl\nu\ne\n \nf\ni\ns\nh"
}
ok: [hana-np-12.cisco.com] => {
    "msg": "B\nl\nu\ne\n \nf\ni\ns\nh"
}
ok: [hana-np-13.cisco.com] => {
    "msg": "B\nl\nu\ne\n \nf\ni\ns\nh"
}
ok: [hana-np-14.cisco.com] => {
    "msg": "B\nl\nu\ne\n \nf\ni\ns\nh"
}
ok: [hana-np-15.cisco.com] => {
    "msg": "B\nl\nu\ne\n \nf\ni\ns\nh"
}
```

How do I properly concatenate a list of strings with the newline character?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

**Solution**

`join` filter works on lists, so apply it to your list:

```
- name: Concatenate the public keys
  set_fact:
    my_joined_list: "{{ my_list | join('\n') }}"
```

---

**Explanation**

While `my_list` in your example is a list, when you use `with_items`, in each iteration`item` is a string. Strings are treated as lists of characters, thus `join` splits them.

It’s like in any language: when you have a loop `for i in (one, two, three)` and refer to `i` inside the loop, you get only one value for each iteration, not the whole set.

---

**Remarks**

- Don’t use `debug` module, but `copy` with `content` to have`\n` rendered as newline.
- The way you create a list is pretty cumbersome. All you need is (quotation marks are also not necessary):

  ```
  - name: Create the list
    set_fact:
      my_list:
        - "One fish"
        - "Two fish"
        - "Red fish"
        - "Blue fish"
  ```

Comment: So it helps to apply the filter to the correct variable. And that's where I am on the learning curve, figuring out which is the correct variable. Once again, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create a multiline string from a list of strings, you can use a jinja2 loop like this:

```yaml
- name: Concatenate the public keys
  set_fact:
    my_joined_list: |
      {% for item in my_list %}
      {{ item }}
      {% endfor %}

- name: Examine the joined string
  debug:
    msg: "{{ my_joined_list }}"
```