# Ansible string split

Tags: ansible, ansible-template

I have a split function in ansible based on a delimiter. But only want to get the first occurance of the delimiter string and the rest as the second string.

```
string: "hello=abcd=def=asd"
string1= string.split("=")[0]
string2= string.split("=)[1..n] (This is what i missing)
```

How can i achieve this in ansible with string.split?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47244834/how-to-join-a-list-of-strings-in-ansible

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Q: **"*Get the first occurrence of the delimiter string and the rest as the second string.*"**

A: Join the rest of the string again

```yaml
  arr: "{{ string.split('=') }}"
  string1: "{{ arr[0] }}"
  string2: "{{ arr[1:]|join('=') }}"
```

Optionally, set the [*maxsplit*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit) parameter to 1

```yaml
  arr: "{{ string.split('=', 1) }}"
  string1: "{{ arr.0 }}"
  string2: "{{ arr.1 }}"
```

Both options give the same result

```yaml
  string1: hello
  string2: abcd=def=asd
```

Comment: it worked well. thanks